# Characterization of group characters

Tags: gr.group-theory

I wonder how to characterize the characters of a (say, finite) group $G$ as special class functions, in particular for the case $G=S_n$ (symmetric group). The answer to this is presumably well known to people working in group theory, so it is more of a reference request.

Any character $\chi$ is "positive" in the sense that given $g_1,...,g_k\in G$, the matrix with coefficients $\chi(g_i^{-1}g_j)$ is positive. In case of $G=S_n$, characters are also known to be integer-valued class functions. Are there any further properties of characters that distinguish them from general class functions, or even a characterization of characters as class functions with a list of properties?

Of course, the characters are exactly those class functions which are linear combinations of the irreducible characters with non-negative integer coefficients, but that is not what I have in mind here.

Comment: There are various necessary conditions: for example $\chi(g)$ must be a sum of $\chi(1)$ roots of unity, of order dividing the order of $g$, and $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle$ must be an integer. I don't know any useful sufficient conditions. If there were really simple sufficient conditions then people wouldn't have to work so hard to write down e.g. the characters of finite groups of Lie type.

Comment: Frieder Ladisch has described Brauer's characterization of characters in his answer below. Since you asked especially about Symmetric groups, it might be of interest to note that Frobenius already knew that a complex class function $\chi$ of a symmetric group $S_{n}$ is a generalized character if and only if $\langle {\rm Res}^{G}_{S_{\underline{\lambda}}}(\chi), 1 \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}$ for each Young subgroup $S_{\underline{\lambda}}$ of $S_{n}.$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best answer I can think of is **[Brauer's characterization of (generalized) characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%27s_theorem_on_induced_characters):** Recall that a *generalized character* is a difference of two characters. A *Brauer elementary group* is a group that is the direct product of a $p$-group and a cyclic group. Then Brauer's theorem states:

> A class function $\chi$ of a finite group $G$ is a generalized character if and only if its restriction $\chi_E$ to each Brauer elementary subgroup $E$ is a generalized character.

This reduces the problem to certain subgroups of restricted structure. Since Brauer elementary groups are monomial, it is equivalent that $[\chi_E, \lambda ] \in \mathbb{Z}$ (inner product for class functions) for all *linear* characters $\lambda$ of all Brauer elementary subgroups $E\leq G$. (Thanks to Geoff Robinson for pointing this out in comment.)

Unfortunately, the word "generalized" can not be omitted from the theorem. We get that a class function $\chi$ is an *irreducible* character if in addition $\chi(1)>0$ and $[\chi,\chi]=1$.

The result is treated, for example, in the books by Isaacs, by Huppert (Character Theory...), or by Serre (Linear Representations of Finite Groups).

Comment: Thanks, that might be helpful in the situation I am looking at ... I will give it a try!